# How to load a tsv file into a Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, input

I'm trying to get a TAB-delimited (`tsv`) file loaded into a `pandas` `DataFrame`.

This is what I'm trying and the error I'm getting:

```
>>> df1 = DataFrame(csv.reader(open('c:/~/trainSetRel3.txt'), delimiter='\t'))

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#28>", line 1, in <module>
    df1 = DataFrame(csv.reader(open('c:/~/trainSetRel3.txt'), delimiter='\t'))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 318, in __init__
    raise PandasError('DataFrame constructor not properly called!')
PandasError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!
```

Comment: For those coming to this answer in 2017+, use `read_csv('path_to_file', sep='\t')`. See [this answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34548894/3707607)

Comment: `read_csv` defaults to comma as the separator, so [`read_table`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9656288/406249) is more convenient for TSV.

Answer (score 281, accepted):

The [.read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) function does what you want:

```
pd.read_csv('c:/~/trainSetRel3.txt', sep='\t')
```

If you have a header, you can pass `header=0`.

```
pd.read_csv('c:/~/trainSetRel3.txt', sep='\t', header=0)
```

**Note**: Prior 17.0, `pd.DataFrame.from_csv` was used (it is now deprecated and [the `.from_csv` documentation link](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_csv.html) redirects to the page for `pd.read_csv`).

Comment: I had some issues with this method - it was very slow and failed indexing at the end. Instead, i used read_table(), which worked much faster and without the extra param.

Comment: I get empty 'columns' and the data are a bunch of mess, can this read tab-separated .txt with the header as first line, I guess not.

Comment: Note that as of 17.0 `from_csv` is discouraged: use `pd.read_csv` instead!

Comment: I had to use the following: 

       DataFrame.read_csv('filepath.tsv', sep=' ', header=0)

Comment: This is a bad answer; you can read TSV natively with `pd.read_csv/read_table`, you just need to set `delim_whitespace=True` or `sep`

Comment: Downvoted because from_csv is deprecated now and you are stil top answer in google

Comment: @rafaelvalle added deprecated notice

Comment: FWIW: Here's a warning message that comes up when using from_csv in jupyter notebook (MacPorts version)

/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:3: FutureWarning: from_csv is deprecated. Please use read_csv(...) instead. Note that some of the default arguments are different, so please refer to the documentation for from_csv when changing your function calls
  This is separate from the ipykernel package so we can avoid doing imports until

Comment: Thanks for sharing this, it works perfectly with `DataFrame.read_csv('c:/~/trainSetRel3.txt', sep='\t')`

Comment: Also if your first column is an index, `index_col=0` is pretty important too

Answer (score 112):

As of 17.0 [`from_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_csv.html) is discouraged.

Use `pd.read_csv(fpath, sep='\t')` or `pd.read_table(fpath)`.

Comment: Note: read_table is deprecated since version 0.24.0. Use pandas.read_csv() instead.

Comment: Apparently `read_table` was later [un-deprecated](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/25220#issuecomment-506848168) in 0.25.0.

Answer (score 70):

Use [`pandas.read_table(filepath)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_table.html). The default separator is tab.

Comment: read_table doesn't require any parameters. Perfectly working.

Answer (score 25):

Try this

```
df = pd.read_csv("rating-data.tsv",sep='\t')
df.head()
```

[image]

You actually need to fix the **sep** parameter.

Answer (score 9):

open file, save as .csv and then apply

```
df = pd.read_csv('apps.csv', sep='\t')
```

for any other format also, just change the sep tag

Answer (score 3):

```
data = pd.read_csv('your_dataset.tsv', delimiter = '\t', quoting = 3)
```

You can use a delimiter to separate data, quoting = 3 helps to clear quotes in datasst

Answer (score 2):

```py
df = pd.read_csv('filename.csv', sep='\t', header=0)
```

You can load the tsv file directly into pandas data frame by specifying delimitor and header.

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_fwf('xxxx.tsv')
```

Comment: Why this instead of `read_csv` with `sep='\t'`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
DataFrame = pd.read_csv("dataset.tsv", sep="\t")
```