# Convert ^I delimited file to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, base64, gmail-api, base64url

I am downloading a csv file from gmail attachment using below code. The output file generated looks like ^I delimited and I am not sure how to change it to some other delimiter so that I can load it into a pandas dataframe.

```
message = service.users().messages().get(userId=user_id, id=msg_id).execute()
for part in message['payload'].get('parts', ''):
    if part['filename']:
        file_name = part['filename']
        att_id = part['body']['attachmentId']
        att = service.users().messages().attachments().get(userId=user_id, messageId=msg_id,
                                                               id=att_id).execute()
        data = att['data']
file_data = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(data.encode('UTF-8'))
with open(path, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(file_data)
```

Output file content is separated like below - 
Location ID^IProcessed Currency Code^IExternal MID^IDBA Name

**Edit 1:**
Now I am using tab as separator but get a different error while reading file into dataframe. Perhaps, it has got something to do with urlsafe_b64decode or data.encode('UTF-8') but I am not able to understand. The actual attachment file in gmail is a tab separated file.

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position
>   0: invalid start byte

Comment: The actual column names are Location ID, Processed Currency Code, External MID, DBA Name

Comment: You can specify the separator while reading a csv with pandas: `pd.read_csv(filename, sep='^|')`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to load a tsv file into a Pandas DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9652832/how-to-load-a-tsv-file-into-a-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: `^I` is another way of representing a tab, so this is likely a tab-separated file.  See the dupe target for how to load.

Comment: @Erfan - I tried that but it is not able to find ^I in file and puts everything into a single column

Comment: Then see the question that is tagged by @snakecharmerb, its `sep='\t'`

Comment: @snakecharmerb - Tried using df = pd.read_csv(path, header=0, sep='\t') and get following error -
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues here:

- the column delimiter `'^I'`
- the encoding of the data

**The delimiter**

`'^I'` is another way of representing the [tab character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tab_key#Tab_characters). Some applications may choose to represent tab characters in this way rather than using the `'\t'` escape sequence.  For example vim displays tabs as `'^I'` when instructed to display non-printing characters.

**Encoding**

`'0xff'` is part of a [byte-order-mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) or BOM - an invisible character sequence used to tell applications about the encoding used to encode text.  The UTF-16 encoding uses the sequence `'0xfe0xff'` to denote big-endian UTF-16 (Python codec 'utf-16-be').  `'0xff0xfe'` denotes little-endian UTF-16 (Python codec 'utf-16-le').  UTf-16 uses two bytes to encode characters, so the order of the bytes is important.

So, to successfully open the attachment, it's necessary to specify that the column delimiter is a tab, and the encoding is UTF-16 (Python can use the BOM to work out which version of UTF-16):

```
pd.read_csv(path, header=0, sep='\t', encoding='utf-16')
```